# Запись и чтение файла Json в память устройства

Tags: android

Есть два метода, один скачивает файл с сервера, и записывает его в память устройства. Использует библиотеку Fetch. Второй метод должен прочитать файл. Никак не пойму свою ошибку - файл создается, но при прочтении выдает "". По логам загрузка проходит нормально.

```
private void BookLoader(int bookId) {
    String bookIdJson = "http://****.ru/todbook/book" + bookId + ".json";
    Fetch bFetch;
    String folderJsB = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();
    String fileName = "list_"+Uri.parse(bookIdJson).getLastPathSegment();
    Request request = new Request(bookIdJson, folderJsB, fileName);
    bFetch = Fetch.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
    bFetch.removeRequests();
    long resD = bFetch.enqueue(request);
    resD = 0;
}
```

Вот код метода для чтения

```
private String GetJson(String fileListBook) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileListBook);
        //check whether file exists
        if(!f.exists()){
            return null;
        }
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        return new String(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Reading: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте прочитать файл этим методом:

```
public static String getStringFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
        String jString;
        File yourFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
        stream.close();
        return jString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Самый простой способ прочитать файл:**

```
public static String readTextFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) result.append(line).append("\n");
    br.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```